# How to change toggle comment from @REM to REM in VS Code

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-code

In VS code, when I toggle a comment, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, it comments the line with `@REM`. How do I change this to comment the line with just `REM`?

Comment: `Rem`arks in a batch file shouldn't be `echo`ed to the end user, they're for viewers of the source code. `@REM` is therefore the most appropriate string to use as it ensures those `rem`arks are never `echo`ed, regardless of whether the `echo` status is `on` or `off`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `\resources\app\extensions\bat` folder of your VSCode installation folder (if you're not sure where that is, check `%localappdata%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code` first), there's a file called `language-configuration.json`. At the very beginning of the file, there's a bit that reads

```
{"comments":{"lineComment":"@REM"}
```

Change this to

```
{"comments":{"lineComment":"REM"}
```

(Note that if VSCode ever updates, you'll have to change this file again.)

Comment: Thanks! This worked after changing the file, then restarting VS Code.

Comment: I am setting up a new computer, and I cannot find the \resources directory, any idea where I could find this?

Comment: @perry_the_python - It's in whatever folder you installed VS Code into. If that folder doesn't have a resources directory, try opening VS Code first; maybe it doesn't get generated until the program loads for the first time or something. If it's still not there after that, VS Code did not install correctly and you need to reinstall it, because that folder is required for VS Code to run properly.

Comment: Coming back to this after two years because _I_ needed help finding the default install folder.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at this extension, [Custom Language Properties](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.custom-language-syntax), that I just released.  Here it is doing what you want for `.bat` batch file `lineComments`:

[image: Custom language properties extension demo on a batch file]

It makes changing comments or brackets for a language or languages pretty easy.  Via a setting like:

```
  "custom-language-properties": {

    "bat.comments.lineComment": "REM",
    "python.comments.lineComment": "# ~",
    "javascript.comments.blockComment": ["/*  ","  */"]
 }
```